# Insert unique value based on auto-incremented column

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table with an id column that is being autoincremented and then there's a tracking_code column that has a unique constraint on it.

Currently the tracking_code is being supplied by the person signing up, but now the client wants that tracking_code to be auto-generated yet be changeable as well.
In other words, where a user signs up, auto-generate the tracking_code, but allow the user to update that code to anything else as long as it stays unique.

Is it possible to do something like this in MySQL (append a string to an autoincremented id which only exists after the record is inserted) or is there another way of doing it in mysql:

INSERT INTO mytable (..., tracking_code, ...) VALUES (..., 'foo-' + id + '-bar', ...)

Comment: Do you really, really need a special column for tracking? Cant you just use id? If not, i would use trigger to change tracking value after insert. Dont know if it is the best solution, but it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  (..., tracking_code, ...)
VALUES (
  ...,
  CONCAT(
    'foo-',
    (
        SELECT
            AUTO_INCREMENT
        FROM
            information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
    ),
    '-bar'
  ),
  ...
)
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SET tracking_code = CONCAT(
    'foo-',
    (
        SELECT
            AUTO_INCREMENT
        FROM
            information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE
            TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
    ),
    '-bar'
),
...
```

Obviously only works if you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Comment: I've added an extra table that just counts inserts, that way the Autoincrement solution is more database independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your tracking id to auto increment, and it will work as you need. When you don't supply a value for tracking id during insert the tracking id will be auto generated, and when you do than the supplied value will be set. Just don't forget to add the unique constraint.